# Getting error while minting token to an account "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction"

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, anchor-lang, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl

My mint test cases are failing and I am clueless where it is going wrong

```
    pub fn mint(ctx: Context<MintToken>, params: MintTokenParams) -> Result<()> {
    // Check user balance first
    require!(params.amount > 0, CustomError::AmountCantBeZero);

    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();

    // let seeds = &["mint_account".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint_account]];
    // let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    // Create the MintTo struct for our context
    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
    };
    // token_2022::mint_to(
    //     CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, &signer),
    //     params.amount,
    // )?;

    token_2022::mint_to(CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts), params.amount)?;

    // Emit mint event
    emit!(MintEvent {
        amount: params.amount
    });

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: MintTokenParams)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is the token that we want to mint
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: This is the token account that we want to mint tokens to
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: the authority of the mint account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}
```

and the test case is

```
      const mint = async (mintTokenParams, pdaMaintainers, mintAccount) => {
    // Creating associated token for user1
    let user1ATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mintAccount,
      user1.publicKey
    );

    // Test mint_token instruction
    let mintToken = await program.methods
      .mintToken(mintTokenParams)
      .accounts({
        maintainers: pdaMaintainers,
        mintAccount: mintAccount,
        toAccount: user1ATA,
        authority: admin.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([admin])
      .rpc();

    await confirmTransaction(mintToken);
  };
```

but I am getting this error

```
  1) token_program
       Test Mint Token:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5922:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5881:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:318:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:149:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

[image]

---

After using `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` I am getting `TokenAccountNotFoundError`

```
const mint = async (mintTokenParams, pdaMaintainers, mintAccount) => {
    // Creating associated token for user1
    let user1ATA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      payer,
      mintAccount,
      user1.publicKey
    );

    // Test mint_token instruction
    let mintToken = await program.methods
      .mintToken(mintTokenParams)
      .accounts({
        maintainers: pdaMaintainers,
        mintAccount: mintAccount,
        toAccount: user1ATA.address,
        authority: admin.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        // rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        // systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        // associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_PROGRAM_ID
      })
      .signers([admin])
      .rpc();

    await confirmTransaction(mintToken);
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the address of your mint account is a pda.

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
```

This means you would need an instruction in your program to create and initialize the mint account (in order to have the address of the mint account as a pda derived from your program).

Have you created the mint account successfully before trying to mint tokens?

Also, what are the `mintTokenParams` your instruction is expecting? The error mentions "invalid instruction data", so the formatting of the `mintTokenParams` might be the issue.

Comment: Hi Can you suggest how to create and initialise the mint account?

`mintTokenParams` is the parameter to the function, it just contains two fields, amount of tokens to be minted and token name, seems to be correct

Comment: here is an [example](https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-starter/blob/main/03-pda-counter-token/programs/counter/src/lib.rs#L101-L109)  you can reference

Comment: Hi John I am initializing it in my create function
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [MINT_TAG, params.token_name.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

so initialization is not the issue

Comment: I have tried passing `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID` to `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` function but still getting same issue `TokenAccountNotFound`, all examples I am getting is for token library, and I am working on token2022
let user1ATA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      payer,
      mintAccount,
      user1.publicKey,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    );

Comment: Check your arguments for the function. Program id is not the fourth argument, it's the 8th. You can pass undefined for the three arguments in between (check my answer). In the absence of explicit program id, the function assumes it to be Token Program and since your Mint belongs to Token-22, it returns the error because it can't find the mint account on-chain with Token Program as the owner.

Comment: @Tarun, also check if  ``maintainers: pdaMaintainers,`` is needed because there is no account with that name on the program side in the code you provided.

Comment: yes @0xShuk you are right passing `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID` to 8th position it worked for me, thanks alot

Comment: Nice, if the issue is resolved, accept the answer to mark the question as accepted.

Comment: Hi while interacting with phantom wallet, again I am getting the same error, for below configuration,

`let user1ATA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      wallet,
      mintAccount,
      wallet?.publicKey,
      undefined,
      undefined,
      undefined,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );`

while test cases are working fine `anchor test --provider.cluster=Localnet`
Error name `TokenAccountNotFoundError error`

Answer (score 5):

Your program expects the token account to be initialized already. Are you initializing it before calling the instruction? If not then it should return the `invalid account data` error like it is doing in your case.

Use `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` instead of `getAssociatedTokenAddress` in the following code and see if it solves the issue for you. Don't forget to mention `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID` as the `programId`:

```
// OLD
let user1ATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mintAccount,
      user1.publicKey
);

//NEW
let user1ATA = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      user1, 
      mintAccount, 
      user1.publicKey, 
      undefined, 
      undefined, 
      {}, 
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);
```